# Concepts in C# 3.0

Tags: c#, c#-3.0, language-features

When a person moves from C# 2.0 C# 3.0 ,what are the concepts does he need to learn?

like **extension method,lambda expression,Linq.**

Comment: "3.0" by itself is a very bad tag.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

They're all listed here:

- [Overview of C# 3.0](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb308966.aspx)

Comment: Thanks Eric.Where can i locate Linq to xml samples in C# ? i have seen only in VB.

Comment: If you get the chance, I think your input on a list of "things most likely to improve your code" would be valuable. :)

Answer (score 1):

Yes that's a good start. You can also go over any kind of "*what's new in C# 3.0*" page, like [this one from MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb308966.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

I can recommend that you have a look at [C# in depth](http://www.manning.com/skeet/) by Jon Skeet too. Very good book. :-)

Answer (score 0):

You could look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9033/hidden-features-of-c) stack overflow question.  It is not C# 3.0 specific, but contains a fair number of features which are very useful, and not known to all programmers.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of now widely used features of C# 3 that one "should" learn.  That said, what you learned while using C# 2 will be just as applicable under C# 3.

The more common C# 3 features that one might encounter when reviewing other's code, wish to understand and ultimately adopt are:

- Automatically Implemented Properties
- Lambda Expressions
- Linq
- Object Initializers